# Limit values for the left Join part of a query

Tags: php, mysql

Please i have four tables joined together using the LEFT JOIN, the images table is linked to the items table by img_item, thus each item can have more images. i want to fetch only the first image of every item. How do i go achieve this.

```
 SELECT   * FROM items
 LEFT JOIN category ON items.item_cat = category.cat_id
 LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id=items.item_user
 LEFT JOIN institutions ON institutions.inst_id=users.user_inst 
 LEFT JOIN images ON images.img_item = items.item_id
 ORDER BY item_id DESC
```

Comment: how you define the first .. the one with the min id  or by a creation date .. which is the criteria for find the first?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can enumerate the results using variables, and then choose the first.  Another alternative is to identify which one you want, and choose that one.  The following chooses the image with the largest id:

```
SELECT *
FROM items LEFT JOIN
     category
     ON items.item_cat = category.cat_id LEFT JOIN
     users
     ON users.user_id=items.item_user LEFT JOIN
     institutions
     ON institutions.inst_id = users.user_inst LEFT JOIN
     images
     ON images.img_item = items.item_id AND
        images.img_id = (SELECT MAX(i2.img_id)
                         FROM images i2
                         WHERE i2.img_item = images.img_item
                        );
ORDER BY item_id DESC
```

Comment: thanks everyone for your support @Gordon it worked for me